# What happens during function proofs

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to proof a property of the icmp6 checksum function (sum 16bit integers, add carry, invert 16bit integer).

I defined the functions in isabelle. (I know my proofs are terrible)

But for some reason, isabelle can't proof something about the `icmp_csum` function, it wants to have.
When I replace the `oops` in the paste with `done` it produces thousands of lines that just says:
"linarith_split_limit exceeded (current value is 9)"

```
theory Scratch
imports Main Int List
begin

fun norm_helper :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
  "norm_helper x = (let y = divide x 65536 in (y + x - y * 65536))"

lemma "x ≥ 65536 ⟹ norm_helper x < x" by simp
lemma h: "norm_helper x ≤ x" by simp

fun normalize :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
  "normalize x = (if x ≥ 65536
    then normalize (norm_helper x)
    else x)"

inductive norm_to :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool" where
  "(x < 65536) ⟹ norm_to x x"
| "norm_to y z ⟹ y = norm_helper x ⟹ norm_to x z"

lemma ne: "norm_to x y ⟹ y = normalize x"
  apply (induct x y rule: norm_to.induct) by simp+

lemma i: "norm_to x y ⟹ x ≥ y"
  apply (induct x y rule: norm_to.induct) by simp+
lemma l: "norm_to x y ⟹ y < 65536"
  apply (induct x y rule: norm_to.induct) by simp+

lemma en: "y = normalize x ⟹ norm_to x y"
  apply (induct x rule: normalize.induct)
proof -
  fix x :: nat
  assume 1: "(x ≥ 65536 ⟹ y = Scratch.normalize (norm_helper x) ⟹ norm_to (norm_helper x) y)"
  assume 2: "y = Scratch.normalize x"  
  show "norm_to x y"
  proof (cases "x ≥ 65536")
    show "¬ 65536 ≤ x ⟹ norm_to x y"
      using norm_to.intros(1)[of x] 2 by simp
    {
      assume s: "65536 ≤ x"
      have d: "y = normalize (norm_helper x)" using 2 s by simp
      show "65536 ≤ x ⟹ norm_to x y"
        using 1 d norm_to.intros(2)[of "norm_helper x" y x]
        by blast
    }
  qed
qed

lemma "normalize x ≤ x" using en i by simp
lemma n[simp]: "normalize x < 65536" using en l by blast

fun sum :: "nat list ⇒ nat" where
  "sum [] = 0"
| "sum (x#xs) = x + sum xs"

fun csum :: "nat list ⇒ nat" where
  "csum xs = normalize (sum xs)"

fun invert :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
  "invert x = 65535 - x"

lemma c: "csum xs ≤ 65535" using n[of "sum xs"] by simp
lemma ic: "invert (csum xs) ≥ 0" using c[of xs] by blast

lemma asdf:
  assumes "xs = ys"
  shows "invert (csum xs) = invert (csum ys)"
  using  HOL.arg_cong[of "csum xs" "csum ys" invert,
                      OF HOL.arg_cong[of xs ys csum]] assms(1)
  by blast

function icmp_csum :: "nat list ⇒ nat" where
  "icmp_csum xs = invert (csum xs)"
apply simp
apply (rule asdf)
apply simp
oops

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why there is tracing output from `linarith` there, but given that your definition is neither recursive nor performs pattern matching, you can write it as a `definition`:

```
definition icmp_csum :: "nat list ⇒ nat" where
  "icmp_csum xs = invert (csum xs)"
```

Another possibility is to change `invert` to a `definition` instead of a `fun`. (In general, if it's neither recursive nor performs pattern matching, `definition` is preferable because it has much less overhead than `fun`.)

NB, just import `Main`, not `Main Int List`.

*Edit:* An explanation from Tobias Nipkow on [the mailing list](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2017-January/msg00020.html):

> This is a known issue. In the outdated LNCS 2283 you can find a discussion what to do about it in Section 3.5.3 Simplification and Recursive Functions. The gist: don't use "if", use pattern matching or "case". Or disable if_split.

Comment: The problem is related to the fact that the definition of `normalize` leads the simplifier to loop: the right-hand side of the definition contains an instance of the left-hande side, so the simplifier can rewrite indefinitely. (actually, the simplifier doesn't normally rewrite under ‘Ifs’ in order to prevent such problems, but some interaction with the splitter seems to lead to infinite rewriting in this case)